# Does it make sense to make all external links to be opened in new tab?

Tags: discussion

May I suppose that all links that point to external sites to be opened in a new tab?

i.e. make an configurable user option that will force to emit `<a target='_blank' href="%outer_world%">Useful external link</a>`

I suppose this could be useful feature for people who contribute often

Answer (score 2):

## No.

- [You should not control](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/) the link behavior on someone else's computer unless you have a good reason to do that;
- Check the [markup guide for links](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links), this is how most of us do it, we don't use `<a>` (except for blatant copy-paste);
- If you need all links opened in the new tab (without pressing Shift), consider installing some browser extension to do that **on your computer, not on mine**. For example, GreaseMonkey for Firefox/Chrome can do the trick. Just write a script that would [do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281486/use-target-blank-in-css) for you.

Comment: Just to clarify: I was curious if it's possible to provide an option to user to open external links in new tab automatically without doing  <Key>CTRL</KEY>-click

Comment: @Chizh, Globally across the StackExchange — no, there would be a revolt:) Locally on your browser — yes, depending on your browser. One solution is in my answer. If you mean, opening in **new tab** contrary to opening in **new window** — yes, the modern browsers do support that.

Comment: yes, thanks. I'm going to take a look at what it will cost me - I've never done such thing before. If I manage to implement this I'll share source code and deliverables

Answer (score 1):

No.

While this could be good for people that "live" on this site, most of the traffic on mature StackExchange site comes from search engines. People just come here for the answer and they want to leave as soon as they got it.